# Why can't my .NET Core controller parse my JSON?

Tags: json, .net-core

So in my angular frontend I am sending this JSON to my backend.

```
[
  {
    "AccountingDate": 20171130,
    "RegistrationNo": 3951,
    "IDKT": "34HS991016",
    "OriginalIDKT": "test",
    "CounterAccountIDKT": "34HS980876",
    "Text": "006-Hest prov-Ytd NOV17",
    "ProjectCode": "078",
    "Currency": "DKK",
    "Balance": 1
  },
  {
    "AccountingDate": 20171130,
    "RegistrationNo": 3951,
    "IDKT": "34JR991016",
    "OriginalIDKT": "test",
    "CounterAccountIDKT": "34JR980876",
    "Text": "006-Hest prov-Ytd NOV18",
    "ProjectCode": "078",
    "Currency": "DKK",
    "Balance": 1
  }
]
```

My .NET Core controller method looks like the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] AccountBookKeeping[] request)
{
    return Ok(request);
}
```

But when debugging the request object will be null. This is my problem.

My AccountBookKeeping model looks like:

```
using System;

namespace GFSUploadAPI
{
    public class AccountBookKeeping
    {
        public int AccountingDate { get; set; }
        public string RegistrationNo { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        public string IDKT { get; set; }
        public string OriginalIDKT { get; set; }
        public string CounterAccountIDKT { get; set; }
        public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
        public float Balance { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps show your Angular code too?

Comment: `"RegistrationNo": 3951,` isn't a `string` value. Are you using 3.0+?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Yes

Comment: `System.Text.Json` is a bit more strict than Json.NET, so that _could_ be the cause of your issues. You can switch back to Json.NET or switch the type used either by your Angular code or your `AccountBookKeeping` class.